# How to unscale data after predictions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with 2 features (price & volume) & 1 predicted variable (price) and use LTSM model to predict next price based on the previous set of prices.

First I scale the dataset:

```
#Scale the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
```

Finally I want to unscale it:

```
#Get the models predicted price values
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
```

But this doesn't work and I get this error:

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (400,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (400,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

What this error means is that: you have scaled two features i.e. price and volume of shape (400,2), however, at the time of unscaling you are giving only the predicted price in shape (400,1)

A simple solution is to use two separate scalers - one that will unscale the response variable i.e. price (and the associated input feature, again the price), and second one for the rest of the features.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add zero-column to the predictions dataset, unscale it and then remove unused colunm. Stupid but works for me )

Comment: The fact that it "works" (i.e. it does not produce any *coding* error) does not mean it is correct. Please see the other answer on what you actually need to do (you should *not* use the invert of the *feature* scaler to unscale the *predictions*).

Comment: In case of LSTM time_series predictions the output is in the same space as input. Old Prices turns into new ones.

Comment: @DmitryIsakov observation is the same as mine. I'm not sure if the scaler works across columns, but by zeroing out the other feature columns used to make the LSTM prediction on price you can unscale the predicted prices into something that gives you actionable entry/exit points.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions.reshape(-1,1)).reshape(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option that may be worth trying is to manually unscale the model predictions by accessing the feature range that was saved in the `scaler` object. We can access the min and the max values using `scaler.data_min_` and `scaler.data_max_` respectively. The formula for the `unscaled_value` would vary based on the scaling method you have used. This one works for MinMaxScaler, so you would need to adjust the definition of the `unscaled_value` if you change the scaling method you use.

```
    # individually unscale the target variable
    def unscale(scaled_value):
        # if target variable is the first column, then, data_max_[0]
        unscaled_value = scaled_value * (scaler.data_max_[0] - scaler.data_min_[0]) + (scaler.data_min_[0])
        return unscaled_value
```

You can then use this function simply by writing

```
    unscale(predictions)
```

I hope this is helpful.